# kotlin debugging: find what changes an observed variable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, debugging, observable

Still new to kotlin.  As most of my debugging experience is now useless, I'm trying to figure out techniques to debug some of the radically new features of this language (using android studio).  So I'm looking for hints, clues, strategies, etc.

#### the specifics

I'm looking to find when a particular variable is set: `error.code` (see breakpoint 2).  It should have been a 401, but for some reason it's been changed to 13!  Attempting to track it down.

The only place I can find where this value is changed in in the observer.  When I set the debugger to stop at breakpoint 1, I can see that `it.code` is already the wrong value.  But when I look at all the usages of error.code, they are all READ instances--no writes!  And the only call to `handleError()` is in the observer code (breakpoint 1).

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

     viewModel.onProvisionError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
         handleError(viewModel.lastContext, it).  // breakpoint 1
     })
```

and later

```
private fun handleError(pc: ProvisionContext, error: ProvisioningError) {
    viewModel.errorCode = error.code    // breakpoint 2  <--first noticed error here
    viewModel.errorString = error.errorString
    error.extraDetails?.let {
        viewModel.errorDetails = it
    }
```

The callstack when breakpoint 1 hits is of no help.  The caller is simply a library: `EventObserver.onChanged()`.  And that's the point: I don't know what's calling the observer with the wrong data.  Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: LiveData passes its value on to observers unchanged when the value is set. It's not changing the value unless it's a customized subclass of LiveData. In this case, there `code` property is evidently being mutated. If it isn't being mutated when you do a usages search, the next thing I would check is whether it's possible that an entirely different class instance (whatever class it is that has a `code` property) has been assigned to the LiveData.

Comment: Yes, I see.  And it looks like something is happening that's confusing me.  Exceptions are being thrown and new instances are being created--each could be changing values without showing up as obvious variable writes.  Hmmm, still have some digging in through code to do.